# How to print a string to serial port without os,in mips

Tags: mips, boot

We can use syscall to print something with spim,like:

```
    la, $a0, mes
    li, $v0, 4
    syscall
```

But after I `tftp 0 file.bin` and `boot` it didn't print anything to the serial port.

While in X86 `int 10h` works.

Comment: `int 10h` provides functions for interfacing with the graphics card. Do you mean [int 14h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-14.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to know what the serial port interface looks like on your target system. For example, if the `Write Control` and `Write Data` registers are located at `0xFFFF0008` and `0xFFFF000C` as they are in SPIM you could do something like this (untested):

```
la $a0, my_asciiz_string
li $a1, 0xFFFF0008

loop:
  lw $t0, ($a1)  # check if the serial port is ready to be written to
  beq $t0, $zero, loop
  nop

  lbu $t0,($a0)  # load one character from the string
  beq $t0,$zero,done
  nop

  addiu $a0,$a0,1
  sw $t0, 4($a1) # write the character to the serial port
  j loop
done:
```